# Steps for pushing offline project project to online assembla repository with subversion and tortoise svn

Tags: visual-studio-2010, svn, tortoisesvn

I have a local project maintained in local SVN repository (although I'm quite new to this source control concept).

I need to push these entire repository (TortoiseSVN repository) to online assembla repository . Can someone tell how to proceed with it and how to work with it?

- **Also can someone mention how does the check out and check in work here in TortoiseSVN and Subversion?**
- **Which one actually works for which?**
- **And lastly the main. How do I push my all commits in local repository to assembla repository?**

Please can someone tell me the steps? My project is in Visual Studio 2010. Working on an Asp.net MVC project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are new to Apache Subversion you can consider the [Version Control with Subversion](http://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/) book (aka the SVNBook) and [TortoiseSVN manual](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/index.html). They are great source of info about Subversion and just a good reading that describes the version-control concepts.

- TortoiseSVN is an [Apache Subversion](http://subversion.apache.org/) **client** for Windows implemented as a Windows shell extension. Apache Subversion is a version control system.
- Aren't you confusing the **[working copy](http://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/basic/version-control-basics/#svn.basic.working-copy)** and **[repository](http://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/basic/version-control-basics/#svn.basic.repository)** terms? BTW you do not *check in* with Subversion. You *commit* your changes to a repository.
- There is no `push` or `pull` in Subversion. You should import your local repository to Assembla. As far as I know you should dump your repository and import it to Assembla, though they may provide some other way to do that. I'm not aware of that unfortunately.